# give local node server a name rather then ip address

Tags: node.js

This might be a stupid question, but i run a business in a strip mall and internet is included (because of this I have no access to the router). the router assigns dynamic ip address and when I set a static ip I lose connection.

is there a way to change the address to my node app from "http:/ /[my-server-ip]:3000" to something like "http:/ /[business-name]:3000". (/ / should be // but stack wont let me post with dead links)

the main reason for this is I have multiple tablets and devices that use this system however recently after they made some changes to the routers setting my computer will be assigned two or three ip addresses a day (I notified the landlord he says its normal). and everytime my ip address changes I lose connection to my app.

is there a possible fix that doesnt require me to host on a web server or enable port forwarding?

perhaps I should reword the question. How do I go about setting up local dns zones from mac? (I know this can be achieved with most linux distros)

Comment: This is *exactly* what DNS servers are for. Set one up, tell your router to use it with a fallback of whatever default is has, and then set up a rule in your DNS server to give whatever name you want to that IP. Magically, all your devices can use that as if you bought a domain for it.

Comment: Or, you can set up a static IP for your server so it never changes.

Comment: So does that mean its not possible. can dns servers be configured similar to a node or xamp server? or were u merely stating that I am asking about name resolution and thats the job of a dns server.

Comment: please read above static ip breaks connection to the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.

Your server IP will always change as the router gives you a new IP address, so change the hosts will not work unless every time the ip on the server changes, you change your ip as well on the devices.

You may try to create an account on dns sites like http://www.noip.com/. They will give you an "external" internet address like mybusiness.noip.com and then you will point your programs on tablets and cell phones to this address.

You will then install a program on your server that will tell noip what the new address is maintaining the same mybusiness.noip.com on them.

Comment: that being said it seems it would be easier to use a database on my website to hold the current ip address of the server and then pass that to a device trying to connect via my website(assuming device is on same network) however this seems extremely hacky... not that what im doing isnt already

Comment: Yeap. That is the problem with changing IPs.